# Multiple subscription in a single component in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription

I came across with a problem when I use [ng-busy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-busy). There are 4 or 5 subscriptions in my component. When I run one they works properly but when I run all in same time, subscriptions wait each other to unsubscribe. In short, loading component is shown while all methods end their requests.

NgBusyModule configuration is following:

```
NgBusyModule.forRoot(
  new BusyConfig({
    message: 'Please wait...',
    backdrop: true,
    template: BusyComponent,
    delay: 0,
    minDuration: 0,
    wrapperClass: 'eng-busy'
  })
)
```

And component is look like following:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getWorkPlaces();
    this.getPension();
 }

  getWorkPlaces() {
    this.workPlaceSubscription = this.cabinetService.getContracts().subscribe(
      workPlaces=> {
        this.workPlaces = workPlaces;
      }
    )
  }

  getPension() {
    this.pensionSubscription = this.cabinetService.getPension().subscribe(
      pension=> {
        this.pension = pension;
      }
    )
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cabinet-data">
  <div [ngBusy]="workPlaceSubscription">
      workPlaces data
  </div>
  <div [ngBusy]="pensionSubscription">
      pension data
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I configure subscriptions to works without depending each other?

Comment: Your subscriptions are independent of each other. `Ng-busy` loader shows on each `Observable` or `Promise` resolve as expected. What you want to achieve?

Comment: @AmitChigadani thanks for your comment. My first method return response in 3 secs but second returns respose 20 secs. My busy component is shown while second return response. But I use each Subscription for each `div`. I hava just add my html.

Comment: If you don't want to show the loader while second method returns, then just don't add `[ngBusy]` attribute to it.

Comment: There are many subscriptions. I added only two of them. I want to display subscriptions for each request and for each div.

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli So, what was your final solution to this?